# How to configure Window Title in Flutter desktop app (linux)?

Tags: flutter, desktop-application

I've created basic Hello World app using Flutter template and now running it on Linux using `flutter run` command.

In application window top panel ("Title bar") there is text `"hello_world"` and I am trying to figure out how to change this default.

[image]

*Note: I am not trying to modify it dynamically. Just need to set it to static text.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the linux folder, locate a file called `my_application.cc` and locate this line of code

```
if (use_header_bar) {
    GtkHeaderBar* header_bar = GTK_HEADER_BAR(gtk_header_bar_new());
    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(header_bar));
    gtk_header_bar_set_title(header_bar, "some_app"); //<----- change this
    gtk_header_bar_set_show_close_button(header_bar, TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_titlebar(window, GTK_WIDGET(header_bar));
  } else {
    gtk_window_set_title(window, "some_app"); //<----- change this
  }
```